# Expected expression in C

Tags: c, xcode, clang

I am trying to test an algorithm in C, but when trying to call the function, I get the error "Expected expression" at the line where I call the function in my main function. Can somebody spot the mistake that is made?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int fwsubst(
            unsigned long n,
            double alpha,
            double **R,  /* two-dimensional array, row-major */
            double *b    /* one-dimensional array */
);

int main(void){


    fwsubst(2 ,5.0,{{2.0,2.0},{4.0,2.8}}, {1.0, 9.6});

    return 0;
}

int fwsubst(
            unsigned long n,
            double alpha,
            double **R,  /* two-dimensional array, row-major */
            double *b    /* one-dimensional array */
){
    double x;

    for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            sum +=  b[i] * R[i][k];
        }
        x = (b[k] - sum)/(alpha + R[k][k]);
        if (!isfinite(x))
            return -1;
        if(alpha + R[k][k] == 0)
            return -1;
        b[k] = x;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) might be of interest, but with multidimensional arrays a separate variable is easier and more idiomatic.

Comment: Aside: is `if (!isfinite(x))
            return -1;` really the coding goal?  I'd expect `if (isfinite(x))
            return -1;` to look for a pole.  (no `!`)

Comment: Note: `double **R` is not a _two-dimensional array_.  It is a [pointer to pointer to double](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+**R).  `R[i]` is a pointer to `double`.  With `double A[3][4]`, [A](https://cdecl.org/?q=double+A%5B3%5D%5B4%5D) is a 2D array.

Answer (score 3):

> OP's code is invalid

```
//             v-------------------v  v--------v Invalid
fwsubst(2 ,5.0,{{2.0,2.0},{4.0,2.8}}, {1.0, 9.6});
```

---

With C99, code can use [compound literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals).

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace enclosed list of initializers is a *compound literal*.  C11dr §6.5.2.5 3

```
int fwsubst(unsigned long n, double alpha, double **R, double *b);

int main(void) {
  fwsubst(2, 5.0,
  //  v------------------------------------------------------------v  nested literal
  //                 v--------------------v, v--------------------v  literal
      (double *[2]) {(double[2]) {2.0, 2.0}, (double[2]) {4.0, 2.8}},
      (double[2]) {1.0, 9.6});
  //  ^--------------------^ literal
}
```

No need to change the function definition.

Comment: Note: the 2 in `[2]` is optional.  e.g. `(double *[]) {(double[]) {2.0, 2.0}, (double[]) {4.0, 2.8}}`.  Depends on what checking is desired.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the proper syntax for an array literal.  You need:

```
fwsubst(2 ,5.0,(double[2][2]){{2.0,2.0},{4.0,2.8}}, (double[2]){1.0, 9.6});
```

And you need to change the function definition to match, since a `double[2][2]` doesn't convert to a `double **` but to a `double (*)[2]`:

```
int fwsubst(
            unsigned long n,
            double alpha,
            double R[n][n],  /* two-dimensional array, row-major */
            double b[n]      /* one-dimensional array */
);

...

int fwsubst(
            unsigned long n,
            double alpha,
            double R[n][n],  /* two-dimensional array, row-major */
            double b[n]      /* one-dimensional array */
){
    ...
```